# Can a .pdf file be saved to a sql 2008 column using coldfusion?

Tags: sql-server-2008, coldfusion

We have hundreds of millions of files, all pdfs, saved to a network drive. A table keeps track of filenames and some info about the file. Can this be taken a step further and just save them into a column of that table?

Is it worth doing? Will this save disc space? Will it affect access speeds?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/736/is-it-better-to-store-images-in-a-blob-or-just-the-url

Comment: That does answer my question, but what would the read/write operation look like in Coldfusion ?

Comment: This covers some of the IO associate with this: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1113-posting-file-data-using-a-base64-encoding-in-coldfusion.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Is it worth doing: Yes. I've done this with some projects. But
   not all.
2. Will this save disc space: I have not done a comparison.
   It probably does though.
3. Will it affect access speeds: Yes, database queries on that table will be effected. The whole reason for my answering is this suggestion...

Use two different tables for pdf storage. In one table keep information regarding the pdf - like timestamp, names, size, etc. Then in another table have the blob data of the pdf file. You'd marry those two tables with a unique ID of course.
This way you can query regarding the pdf without losing speed.

Comment: Just thought I'd add... this method also works well for caching XML responses from external data sources. Meta data in one table, and the XML data dumped in the other table.